# Java Serialization Comparator

Tags: java, serialization, comparator

Is it possible to serialize a TreeMap with a comparator??

I've tested and it serializes well a treemap without comparator, when you add the comparator, it throws an exception.

If I declare comparator as transient, it still doesn't work. It only works if I make every tree map transient but it doesnt serialize the trees in that case.

Comment: Objects of which class are you trying to serialize?

Comment: all classes in program are implementing and importing serialize.

this is a zoo class

Comment: Please provide the exception.  It sounds like your comparator is not serializable but the stack trace would show which class is failing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All the classes which you attempt to serialize must implement the `java.io.Serializable` interface. Also, each member variable in your class should be `Serializable`. In fact, your whole hierarchy should be.

Comment: this **must** be the correct answer. http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/NotSerializableException.html

Comment: that might be the problem, I've gogoled a bit and don't know if treemap with comparator is serializable

Comment: TreeMap is Serializable. Look elsewhere.

Comment: treemap is but treemap with comparator is not. Thats what's killing me. I've serialized with the comparator and doesn't work, without it works fine.

Comment: make your comparator implement Serializable. declare it as a private class, instead of an anonymous clas.

Answer (score 1):

**java.util.TreeMap** is not a problem, your **comparator** probably is.

All you need to do is rewrite your comparator class

```
// throws a 'java.io.NotSerializableException'
class ThisIsNotSerializable implements Comparator<String> {
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
}

class ThisIsSerializable implements Comparator<String>, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5972458403679726498L;

    public int compare(String arg0, String arg1) {
        return arg0.compareTo(arg1);
    }
}
```

more info & [source](https://help.semmle.com/wiki/display/JAVA/Non-serializable+comparator)

Answer (score 0):

For more help, look at [this](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/).  Other things to consider (as mentioned in this document and elsewhere):

- versioning
- custom serial forms for objects
- what fields of your object should be serialized and which ones are *transient*

Comment: I read it and in forms it appears treemap as serializable as it is and field comparator in there but after some testing it doesn't work either.

I was looking at this page:
http://www.cs.chalmers.se/~catarina/java1.5/jsr-14-public-draft/collections-javadoc/serialized-form.html

Answer (score 0):

TreeMap isn't doing anything special, here.  If the only difference between a TreeMap that serializes and one that doesn't is your comparator... then your comparator is not serializable.

How are you implementing the comparator?  Your transient declaration is meaningless to the TreeMap class which does not have a transient reference.

What does the exception say?

Answer (score -1):

You might find that it is as simple as changing the Comparator field to a static rather than an instance member:

```
public final static Comparator<String> ID_IGN_CASE_COMP
```

You will need to make sure that all the other fields are Serializable but this should be a start.

Comment: It isn't because of it, comparator isn't serializable, but even if I declare it as transient, it still throws because of TreeMap that uses teh comparator.

Comment: Then the answer is surely to make the Comparator Serializable.